Forward a single port to KVM Virtual Machine with Libvirt
I have a KVM that is currently running PBX software, and a OpenVPN server. I want to give a friend an IP Phone. I am connecting IP Phones to the OpenVPN Server so that they can communicate with the PBX more securely. However, these phones don't support the latest OpenVPN Cryptography (EASYRSA_DIGEST needs to be set to SHA1), so I want to isolate the VM that is running the PBX from the internet, but still allow the OpenVPN traffic to be passed from the host machine to the VM.
What would be the best way to do this? I have tried already to set the network mode to isolated and use iptables to forward the openvpn server port, however I was unable to get this to work. I also tried using libvirt network filters to filter all traffic except on the openvpn port, however I was unable to successfully have the filter do anything. What would be the ideal solution?
